# which files should be added to Souce Control (Service Reference)

Tags: asp.net, wcf, service-reference

When i added service reference to my .Net project (right click->Add Service Reference), VS created a folder with the Service name and created bunch of files (listed below). I am not sure which files should be added to the source control so that next time when i upgrade the service reference, i dont end up deleting some files and adding new files. List of files that VS created in the service folder are as below:

```
ConfigurationService.disco
ConfigurationService.wsdl
ConfigurationService.xsd
ConfigurationService1.xsd
ConfigurationService2.xsd
ConfigurationService1.wsdl
ConfigurationService3.xsd
ConfigurationService4.xsd
configuration91.svcinfo
configuration.svcinfo
Reference.svcmap
Reference.cs
abc.datasource
def.datasource
ghi.datasource
jkl.datasource
mno.datasource
pqr.datasource
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually we add the whole folder with all its files, you can safely do that.

user specific files are not created in that subfolder.

Consider that when you will update the reference some files will be edited and others will not be touched. If some are fully regenerated TFS or the source control system you are using will get the changes, not the deletion and re-add as another file with same name; at least I would expect so and never seen anything different happening.

Comment: It's been my experience that refreshing a proxy doesn't always work.  The only way to reliably regenerate is to delete and rebuild the proxy.

Comment: i dont have problem with the files being edited. That should happen anyways. I dont like new files being generated every time and some old files being deleted bcz it takes me one day to get approval of adding new files to source control.